# How to Implement function return from http request

Tags: javascript, rest, openidm

I have an ajax call as follow

```
  $.ajax({
    datatype:'json',
    url: 'http://localhost:9090/openidm/policy/managed/user/'+storeUserId,
    type:'get',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    } ,   
    corssDomain:true,
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest" 
    }, 
    success: function (result){
        var validations = result.properties[1].policies[1];
        console.log(validations.policyFunction);
    },
    error:function (error){
        console.log (error);
    }
   });
});
```

The above ajax call return the policyFunction as follow :

```
    function (fullObject, value, params, property) {
    var isRequired = _.find(this.failedPolicyRequirements, function (fpr) {
        return fpr.policyRequirement === "REQUIRED";
    }), isNonEmptyString = (typeof (value) === "string" && value.length), hasMinLength = isNonEmptyString ? (value.length >= params.minLength) : false;
    if ((isRequired || isNonEmptyString) && !hasMinLength) {
        return [{"policyRequirement":"MIN_LENGTH", "params":{"minLength":params.minLength}}];
    }
    return [];
}
```

i wanna to implement that function in my javascript file. Like passing parameters to that function. So how can i implement.

Comment: is typeof validations.policyFunction == 'function' ?

Comment: Do you mean this linke of code ?
var validations = result.properties[1].policies[1];

Comment: It is text if i am not wrong

Comment: yes correct. it is.

Comment: yes I know that it wont be exactly function type. it will be a string

Comment: so how can i pass parameters into that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke it in the browser like so:

```
policyFunction = eval("(" + validations.policyFunction + ")");

failures = policyFunction.call({ failedPolicyRequirements: [] },
    fullObject,
    value,
    params,
    propertyName);
```

Where fullObject is the entire object, value is the value of the particular property, params are any parameters needed within the validation function, and propertyName is the name of the property.